# Solving for polynomial roots in Stata

Tags: stata, finance, function

I am trying to solve for the roots of a function in Stata. There is the "polyeval" command under Mata, but I am not sure how to apply it here. It seems to me as if under polyeval functions must follow a very clear structure of x^2 + x + c.

I would like to find out more about how to use Stata to solve this type of problem in general. But here is my current one, if that provides some idea of what I am working with.
I am currently trying to solve the Black (1976) American Options pricing model:

```
C = e^{-rt} [ F N(d1) - E N(d2)]
where, 
d1 = [ln(F/E) + 1/2 simga^2 t] / [sigma sqrt{t}]
d2 = d1 - sigma sqrt{t}
```

where C is the price of call option, t is time to expiration, r is interest rate, F is current futures price of contract, E is strike price, sigma is the annualized standard deviation of the futures contract. N(d1) and N(d2) are cumulative normal probability functions. All variables are known except for sigma.

As an aside, this seems to be really easy to do in R:

```
fun <- function(sigma) exp(-int.rate* T) * (futures * pnorm((log(futures/Strike)+ sigma^2 * T/2) / sigma * sqrt(T),0,1)- Strike * pnorm((log(futures/Strike)+ sigma^2 * T/2) / sigma * sqrt(T)- sigma * sqrt(T),0,1) ) - Option

uni <- uniroot(fun, c(0, 1), tol = 0.001 )
uni$root
```

Does anyone have any ideas/pointers on how to use Stata to solve this type of function?

Comment: Have you tried to  google "Stata root finder"?

Comment: Thank you, I did. I am still not sure how to use any of the advise that I see given out. Do you have any tips for mata beginners on how to use such a thing?

Comment: I can only suggest you get comfortable with Mata; google "learn Mata". Also, in Stata, type `ssc install moremata`. This package includes two root-finding functions.